# Unitary matrix has eigenvalues of 1 or -1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A\in M_n(C)$

\begin{pmatrix} 1 
 & 0&0 \\
 0& i & 0\\ 
 0& 0 & i
\end{pmatrix}

$AA^*=A^*A=I_3$ so the matrix is unitary but the eigenvalues are $1, i$.

the eigenvalues not supposed to be just $1$ or $-1$? am I wrong?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a unitary matrix lie on the unit circle, as they do here.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so it can be 1,-1,i,-i?

Comment: The eigenvalues are supposed to be $\pm 1$ only if you have a reason to believe that they should be real.

Comment: Not only that, anything on the unit circle.

Comment: @UltimateMath and a lot more!

Answer (score 2):

The matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos t & -\sin t & 0 \\
\sin t & \cos t & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
is easily seen to be unitary (actually real orthogonal) for every real $t$. Its eigenvalues are $1$, $\cos t+i\sin t$ and $\cos t-i\sin t$.

A *real* eigenvalue of a unitary matrix can only be $1$ or $-1$; but generally unitary matrices have complex eigenvalues all with modulo $1$. Indeed, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the unitary $U$, with eigenvector $v$, we have
$$
v^Hv=v^HU^HUv=(Uv)^H(Uv)=(\lambda v)^H(\lambda v)=\bar{\lambda}\lambda v^Hv
=|\lambda|^2(v^Hv)
$$
forcing $|\lambda|^2=1$ and so $|\lambda|=1$. Nothing more can be said, because it's quite easy to make a unitary matrix having as eigenvalues whatever complex numbers of modulo $1$ you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong. A complex number $\omega$ is an eigenvalue of some unitary matrix if and only if $|\omega|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \in \mathbb C$ with$|\lambda_j|=1$ for $j=1,...,n$, then

$$A= diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n )$$

is unitary and the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n $.